# AWS Cloud formation Template Error - Encountered unsupported function: Fn::ToJsonString

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

When I try to deploy my API Gateway using `sam build/sam deploy`
I get an error:

```
Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: my-api, ex: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Status" we matched expected path: "FAILED" Status: FAILED. Reason: Template Error: Encountered unsupported function: Fn::ToJsonString Supported functions are: [Fn::Base64, Fn::GetAtt, Fn::GetAZs, Fn::ImportValue, Fn::Join, Fn::Split, Fn::FindInMap, Fn::Select, Ref, Fn::Equals, Fn::If, Fn::Not, Condition, Fn::And, Fn::Or, Fn::Contains, Fn::EachMemberEquals, Fn::EachMemberIn, Fn::ValueOf, Fn::ValueOfAll, Fn::RefAll, Fn::Sub, Fn::Cidr]
```

I didn't change anything in the template.yaml and this worked and deployed before fine.
I only changed api.yaml.

After I rollback those changes, the problem is still there.

My template.yaml:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform:
    - AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
    - AWS::LanguageExtensions
Description: >
    Service root

Parameters:
    EnvType:
        Description: 'Environment type'
        Default: test
        Type: String
        AllowedValues: ['prod', 'dev', 'stage', 'test']
    DefaultServicesVersion:
        Default: latest
        Type: String
    ServicesPrefix:
        Type: String
        Default: ''
    DomainName:
        Type: String
        Default: api.link
    EdgeCertificateArn:
        Type: String
        Default: ''
    HostedZoneId:
        Type: String
        Default: ''
    WafRateLimit:
        Type: Number
        Default: '100'
    WafCountryCodes:
        Type: String
        Default: 'DE'
    JwtAudience:
        Type: String
        Default: 'dee'
    JwtIssuer:
        Type: String
    JwksUri:
        Type: String

Conditions:
    IsEnvProd: !Equals [!Ref EnvType, 'prod']
    IsEnvTest: !Equals [!Ref EnvType, 'test']
    IsEnvNotTest: !Not [!Equals [!Ref EnvType, 'test']]

Globals:
    Api:
        TracingEnabled: true 
        OpenApiVersion: 3.0.1 
    Function:
        Timeout: 5 # Default timeout is 5 seconds
        Handler: lambda.handler
        Runtime: nodejs18.x
        Environment:
            Variables:
                AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: 1
Resources:
    RestApi:
        Condition: IsEnvNotTest
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
        Properties:
            Name: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-api'
            StageName: !Sub ${EnvType}
            AccessLogSetting:
                DestinationArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:DeeCloudWatchApiLogs:*'
                Format:
                    Fn::ToJsonString:
                        Fn::Transform:
                            Name: AWS::Include
                            Parameters:
                                Location: './routes/access-log-settings.json'
            Tags:
                monitoring: SLO
                budgeting: SLO
            DefinitionBody:
                Fn::Transform:
                    Name: AWS::Include
                    Parameters:
                        Location: './routes/api.yaml'
            Domain:
                CertificateArn: !Sub '${EdgeCertificateArn}'
                DomainName: !Sub '${DomainName}'
                EndpointConfiguration: EDGE
                Route53:
                    HostedZoneId: !Sub '${HostedZoneId}'
                    EvaluateTargetHealth: true

    RestApiAuthorizer:
        Condition: IsEnvNotTest
        Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer'
        Properties:
            AuthorizerCredentials: !GetAtt
                - LambdaAuthorizerInvocationRole
                - Arn
            AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds: '3600'
            AuthorizerUri: !Join
                - ''
                - - 'arn:aws:apigateway:'
                  - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
                  - ':lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/'
                  - !GetAtt
                    - RestApiAuthorizerFunction
                    - Arn
                  - /invocations
            Type: TOKEN
            IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
            Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-api-authorizer
            RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
            IdentityValidationExpression: ^Bearer [-0-9a-zA-z\.]*$

    LambdaAuthorizerInvocationRole:
        Condition: IsEnvNotTest
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: '2012-10-17'
                Statement:
                    - Effect: Allow
                      Principal:
                          Service:
                              - lambda.amazonaws.com
                              - apigateway.amazonaws.com
                      Action:
                          - 'sts:AssumeRole'
            Policies:
                - PolicyName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-AWSLambdaRole
                  PolicyDocument:
                      Version: '2012-10-17'
                      Statement:
                          - Effect: Allow
                            Action:
                                - 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
                            Resource: '*'

    RestApiAuthorizerFunction:
        Condition: IsEnvNotTest
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            FunctionName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-api-authorizer-func
            CodeUri: auth/jwt-rsa-auth/src/
            Environment:
                Variables:
                    JWT_AUDIENCE: !Ref JwtAudience
                    JWT_ISSUER: !Ref JwtIssuer
                    JWKS_URI: !Ref JwksUri
                    NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED: 0 #TODO: WARNING - DEV ONLY. Security Major issue. Remove later
            Role: !GetAtt
                - LambdaAuthorizerInvocationRole
                - Arn
            Tags:
                monitoring: SLO
                budgeting: SLO
            Policies:
                - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
                - Version: '2012-10-17'
                  Statement:
                      - Effect: Allow
                        Principal:
                            Service:
                                - apigateway.amazonaws.com
                        Action:
                            - 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
                        Resource: !GetAtt RestApiAuthorizer.Arn

    TestingRestApi:
        Condition: IsEnvTest
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
        Properties:
            Name: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-testing-api'
            StageName: !Sub ${EnvType}
            AccessLogSetting:
                DestinationArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:DeeCloudWatchApiLogs:*'
                Format:
                    Fn::ToJsonString:
                        Fn::Transform:
                            Name: AWS::Include
                            Parameters:
                                Location: './routes/access-log-settings.json'
            Tags:
                monitoring: SLO
                budgeting: SLO
            DefinitionBody:
                Fn::Transform:
                    Name: AWS::Include
                    Parameters:
                        Location: './routes/api.yaml'

    WafModule:
        Condition: IsEnvProd
        Type: CG::Security::RestApiWaf::MODULE
        Properties:
            RestApi: !Sub ${RestApi}
            RestApiStage: !Sub ${RestApi.Stage}
            WafRateLimit: !Sub ${WafRateLimit}
            WafCountryCodes: !Sub ${WafCountryCodes}

    ApiGatewayStepFunctionsRole:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
            Path: !Join ['', ['/', !Ref 'AWS::StackName', '/']]
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: 2012-10-17
                Statement:
                    - Sid: AllowApiGatewayServiceToAssumeRole
                      Effect: Allow
                      Action:
                          - 'sts:AssumeRole'
                      Principal:
                          Service:
                              - apigateway.amazonaws.com
            Policies:
                - PolicyName: CallStepFunctions
                  PolicyDocument:
                      Version: 2012-10-17
                      Statement:
                          - Effect: Allow
                            Action:
                                - 'states:StartExecution'
                            Resource: '*'
                - PolicyName: DescribeStepFunctionExecutions
                  PolicyDocument:
                      Version: 2012-10-17
                      Statement:
                          - Effect: Allow
                            Action:
                                - 'states:DescribeExecution'
                            Resource: '*'
Outputs:
    ApiEndpoint:
        Description: API Endpoint
        Export:
            Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-ApiEndpoint
        Value:
            Fn::If:
                - IsEnvTest
                - !Sub 'https://${TestingRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${TestingRestApi.Stage}'
                - !Sub 'https://${DomainName}'
```

I tried the previous versions, but it didn't help.

I tried reorder `AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31` and `AWS::LanguageExtensions` in the transform block, but it didn't help

I don't understand what the problem could be.